# Create vector through ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I've got two values in my global environment associated with columns starting Priority_ one is called week and one is called rest.

Week can be any number from 01 to 52

While rest can be 2018, 2017, 2016.

I'm creating an ifelse statement that if the week is equal to 3 and the year is equal to 2017 then the vector output needs to go to year 2016 and week 52. **This equals to week = 3 and rest = Priority_2017**

This is the code I use to create the vector:

```
test<-function(year){
  c(paste0(rest, seq(week, by = -1, length.out=3)),paste0(year,52))  
}
```

Then because the year before 2017 is 2016 I enter:

```
test("Priority_2016")
```

Gives the output:

```
[1] "Priority_20173"  "Priority_20172"  "Priority_20171"  "Priority_201752"
```

I want to add this into an ifelse statement as rest and week will change, I try and use the below code:

```
test<-function(year){
  ifelse((rest %in% c("Priority_2018", "Priority_2017","Priority_2016") & week ==3), c(paste0(rest, seq(week, by = -1, length.out=3)),paste0(year,52)),0)
  }
```

But when I put in:

```
    test("Priority_2016")
```

this only outputs:

```
[1] "Priority_20173"
```

Please let me know if you need any more information from me.

Comment: can you post rest and week?

Comment: @AdamWarner Changed the post a bit as I found some mistakes, sorry.

Comment: you still need to put rest and week...

Comment: @AdamWarner I have, it's in bold even.